# jBoss changes log level itself

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-eap-6

We've observed quite a few times now, that our production jboss (EAP 6.1), changes its log level to DEBUG by itself.

This allways happens after the application runs a few days without any problem. But then, the log level drops to debug for all categories (e.g. Hibernate debug log)
We also have a size rotating file handler, with a configured log file size of 100MB. But if the log level drops, the files get larger and larger (last week, we have a 6GB log file)

Till now, we have no idea what happens or what could be the cause.

Perhaps someone out there has an idea, where to start investigating?

Comment: How are you setting the log level in the first place?

Comment: Via the standalone.xml. All loggers are set to INFO/WARN. The root logger is set to INFO. If we check the admin console, after the jboss starts debug logging, the logging configuration is still correct. Loggers are set to info, but jboss logs debug.

Comment: Are you doing this while the server is running? You can't do that. Use the CLI to change the log levels

Comment: We don't change log levels. We've used the admin console just to check the configuration. And the configuration is correct.

Comment: Does your application include a log4j.xml, log4j.properties or logging.properties file? An example of the debug statements would help as well. For example are they debug messages from your application or from the server?